# Automatically updating equals() and hashCode() methods in classes with added fields.

Tags: java, automation, equals, apache-commons, hashcode

Generating `equals()` and `hashCode()` is simple thing and IDE's help to generate them easily. But when time pass there may be more new fields getting add to Objects. When  complexity of the project goes higher(Number of Object use in the code goes higher) that may become more complex to generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` time to time.

The moment add new fields to bean that person must regenerate `equals()` and `hashCode()` method again. If some one forgot to regenerate this will cause a failure.

I was unable to find a way to update `equals()` and `hashCode()` automatically at the moment add a new field. I found some interesting way with [apache.commons.builder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/package-summary.html)

Now we can override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in following way.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, o);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}
```

Now adding a new field not an issue to use this same `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Now my question, Is there better way to do this.  Again this way we can use `toString()` method too.

Comment: You can use ANT script to update equals and hashcode. create one target xml file. Ia a new field is added modify that xml file and then run ant script.

Comment: why generate the equals() and hashCode() again if a new field was added? that are a few lines of code who can everyone add to the methods by his own.

Comment: Not all classes should need an equals() and hashCode() implementation.  Most of the time, not having them is the right thing. And for those that need one, then blindly implement them by using all the fields they contain is generally not a good idea: you have to think about when two objects must be equal or not.

Comment: add unique id's to the objects, then you never have to compare all fields.

Comment: @kai that's not a very good idea. It'll completely destroy the usefulness of the equals method, as well as breaking Maps and Sets.

Answer (score 3):

The equals and hashCode methods are called too many times, for example , in many of the collections. My vote will be to avoid the use of reflection in above methods.

Guava has  another approach to this.  [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) 
Quote

> AutoValue provides an easier way to create immutable value classes, with a lot less code and less room for error, while not restricting your freedom to code almost any aspect of your class exactly the way you want it.

Comment: Yes. It will cause to slow down the system. your point taken.

Comment: If the object is not used in a Collection, i.e. equals() is seldom used, this might be o.k.

Comment: @ user949300: It is difficult say if the object will be used in a collection or not. IMHO either you should have a good and correct implementation of above APIs or just not have them.

Comment: @Jayan. EqualsBuilder is "good and correct" assuming it includes the correct fields, as you very correctly note.  It is just slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you need speed, and your object is immutable, you could calculate the hashcode once at construction using slow reflection (or lazily later) and store in a field.

Comment: Yes this is how `String` class does it.

Comment: But this doesn't address the question, which is "how can I make sure that all the attributes of the object are used in equals/hashcode".

Comment: @Kayaman. If you want all fields, use equalsBuilder().  However, as Jayan notes, you may want a subset of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Project Lombok is a plugin/library for various IDEs that lets you declare boiler plate code using annotations. They have one such annotation:[EqualsAndHashCode](http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html)

Here is some sample code to illustrate use:

```
  import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

   @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"id", "shape"})
   public class EqualsAndHashCodeExample {
   private transient int transientVar = 10;
   private String name;
   private double score;
   private Shape shape = new Square(5, 10);
   private String[] tags;
   private int id;

   public String getName() {
     return this.name;
   }

   @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
   public static class Square extends Shape {
     private final int width, height;

     public Square(int width, int height) {
       this.width = width;
       this.height = height;
     }
   }
}
```

The main advantage is that you can exclude fields (top examples) and also use fields in superclasses (second example).